# Inner join tables not working php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to inner join two tables where the id is => $_GET['id'] from URL bar.

Tables looks like this->

[forum]

- id
- rubrik
- skapad

[forumthread]

- id
- rubrikid
- namn
- text
- date

My code looks like this, but the site doesn't work. I want the specific id to bring out the information from both tables.

```
<?php
                            $dbh = new PDO(
                            'mysql:host=host;dbname=dbnameds;charset=utf8','user','pass'
                            );  
                            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

                            if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
                            $sql = "SELECT id, rubrik, skapad FROM forum INNER JOIN forumthread ON forum.id = forumthread.rubrikid WHERE forum.id = :id";
                            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                            $stmt->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            ?>
```

Comment: and i dont see your where clause in sql to get data for ur id

Comment: How do you mean? WHERE forum.id = :id? Isn't that enough? :S

Comment: is should return you one records how many you are getting ?

Comment: Your problem statement is not helpful: *doesn't work*.  What about it is wrong? Does it return no records? Too many records? Too few records? What do you expect it to do? What does it do?

Comment: No records. the page shows a text that the page doesnt work, HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: I want to create a forum. The table 'Forum' contains the threads. Table 'forumthreads' contains the posts. I want to join them together to fetch a $_GET['id'] to a specific thread in table 'Forum' and collect all posts in table 'forumthread' where rubrikid has the same value

Comment: UPDATE: I noticed that I had forgotten to add a } in the end. But that didn't help that much except get the site to work. The data doesnt however show up

Comment: Try:  $sql = "SELECT id, rubrik, skapad FROM forum INNER JOIN forumthread ON forum.id = forumthread.rubrikid WHERE forum.id = 1"; I think u might have a Syntax Problem here.

Comment: It doesnt work.. no data is showing..